# Break from rescue if not nil

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

I'm trying to break out of this loop when a date is successfully parsed.

```
def bad_date(date)
  BAD_DATES.each do |bad_date|
    begin
      DateTime.strptime(date.tr(' ', '').tr(':', ''), bad_date)
    rescue ArgumentError
      return nil # else return good date?
    end
  end
end
```

And `BAD_DATES` looks like this:

```
BAD_DATES = ['%H%M%p%m/%d/%Y', '%H%M%p%d/%m/%Y', '%l%M%m/%d/%Y',
           '%H%p%m/%d/%Y', '%H%M%m/%d/%Y'].freeze
```

How can I return the first "good" date from that method?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You have a method `bad_date` that returns a `Date` object or `nil`, and a string that can only be converted to a `Date` object (using `strptime`) if a matching format string is found within `BAD_DATES`. Assuming that is correct, am I the only one that finds these names to be a bit odd? If we were speaking of different types of dates (meetings of couples or the fruit), I would understand the difference between "good date" and "bad date", but that doesn't apply to `Date` objects. How about `string_to_date` for the method name and `DateFormats` for the constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?:

```
def bad_date(date)
  BAD_DATES.each do |bad_date|
    begin
      return DateTime.strptime(date.tr(' ', '').tr(':', ''), bad_date)
    rescue ArgumentError
      # keep going
    end
  end
  return nil
end
```